# null pointer exception even before calling other method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi i have following method

```
public boolean execute(Contract contract)
{

        //validation here
    MassUpdateDao massUpdateDao=new MassUpdateDao();
        contract.setTestSegment(massUpdateDao.retrieveTestDateSegments(contract));
        if(contract.getProdSegments().size()>0)
        {
            String message="validated";
            contract.setMessage(message);

        }


        else
        {
            contract.setAbortFlag(true);
            String message="validation fail";
            contract.setMessage(message);

        }
        return true;

    }
```

It is throwing null pointer exception as soon as i call this method before even executing the   contract.setTestSegment(massUpdateDao.retrieveTestDateSegments(contract)).May i know how i can resolve this.

Comment: Please share the stack trace.

Comment: Could you show us what the constructor MassUpdateDao does also ?

Comment: @KaipaMSarma:I have debugged this but as soon as pointer comes to   contract.setTestSegment(massUpdateDao.retrieveTestDateSegments(contract)) it prints null pointer exception

Comment: yep, either contract or massUpdateDao can be null. Put some logging to print those two objects(or do some debugging) to make sure whether are they null or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the problem is that contract is null. A null pointer exception will be thrown whenever you call a method on null eg null.doSomething()

Comment: What if am setting this in other class contract.setTestSegment(massUpdateDao.retrieveTestDateSegments(contract)) and only calling validationService.execute(contract) even then its printing null pointer exception and this is sure that contract is not null.

Comment: To be sure write System.out.println(contract) just before you get the exception and see if it prints null. As others have pointed out, if you post the stack trace, it will be much easier to help you.